# Duplicate record name in dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ses

Currently I have a TXT record with record name `example.com` for Amazon SES. I will be adding another TXT record for DMARC with the same record name. Will the TXT record in Table 1 be overwritten by Table 2?

**Table 1**

```
|Record Name|Record Type|Record Value|
|:----------|:----------|:-----------|
|example.com|TXT        |amazonses:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=|
```

**Table 2**

```
|Record Name|Record Type|Record Value|
|:----------|:----------|:-----------|
|example.com|TXT        |"v=DMARC1;p=reject;pct=100;rua=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com;ruf=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com;adkim=s"|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each TXT record is a TXT record on its own. They are separate. Same for any other type, if a name has two `A` records, they are not "overwritten".  DNS handles records sets, so a multiple name can resolve to multiple values, for each type (with some exception like `CNAME` that can happen only once).